# Using grailsLinkGenerator to generate link to images in bootstrap.groovy

Tags: grails

I'm trying to create a link to an image resource in my bootsrap file using the underdocumented grailsLinkGenerator class in Grails 2.0.3

I have successfully injected the service using

```
...
LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator 
...
```

But the url generated by the following code is not correct

```
grailsLinkGenerator.resource(dir:'images', file:'1.jpg')
```

There are no errorsm and the path generated almost looks correct, except it is missing 'static' in the url. Am I using this wrong? Is there an alternative way to access your static resources in bootstrap?

Comment: Just to get the picture of your problem: why you need to generate this links on Bootstrap?

Comment: @SérgioMichels I have a 'tshirt' domain, each of which has a 'thumbnailImageUrl'. In bootstrap, I wanted to create a few demo tees with images hosted in web-app/images (in general use, this will be a link e.g. to an s3-hosted image, or something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `ApplicationTagLib` source, you can see that `g:resource` uses `linkGenerator` only when the resources plugin is not installed.

```
Closure resource = { attrs ->
    if (!attrs.pluginContextPath && pageScope.pluginContextPath) {
        attrs.pluginContextPath = pageScope.pluginContextPath
    }
    // Use resources plugin if present, but only if file is specified - resources require files
    // But users often need to link to a folder just using dir
    return ((hasResourceProcessor && attrs.file) ? r.resource(attrs) : linkGenerator.resource(attrs))
}
```

So this is probably the reason that your links don't have the static path.

I don't think that's a good option to store the full link to the thumbnail in the database. If you change something in the structure you will need to update all links. You can store the name of the thumbnail (or use a convention) and let the link be generated in a `TagLib` that will be responsible to show them.

In the TagLib you can just use `g:resource` that will create the correct url's.

Comment: Great idea, I think using a convention then generating the link in a taglib is the way to go.